Firefox Already Running When Using Thunderbird
Debian 12 (Linux 6.1.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.90-1 (2024-05-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux)

When Firefox is running as the default browser and I click on a link in Thunderbird, I always get the message

Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile.

This as well as other solution recommendations work but are not sustainable. Closing Firefox each time before opening a link in an email is not really practicable.
Are there others experiencing the same?
What to do about it?
It seems that Chromium does not show up with this problem.

@eyoung100: Thank you  for improvements.

Not a problem.  That's what reputation is for( more rep = more responsibility) but I have to ask.  Do a lot of parents post computing questions on that exchange? I've peeked but don't see many...

I had a not-quite similar problem, caused by a corrupt desktop file. Removing the file ./.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop fixed it. See https://superuser.com/q/1792660.

@Peterbill: sounds logical, if Thunderbird starts Firefox via a desktop file. However, I can not find a firefox.desktop file in my Linux. I am starting Firefox from a launcher in XFCE panel where it was placed automatically at installation time.
